# sending a variable from code-behind to .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How I can send a variable from code-behaind to .aspx file :

code-behind:
variable **FilePathName**

.aspx:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:TextBox>
    <frameset cols="100%,*">
        <frame name="main" target="main" src="FilePathName">
    </frameset>

</div>
</form>
```

How I can send FilePathName to src in .aspx

Thanks,
Ahmed.

***************** *U P D A T E* *****************
This is Code-Behind and my goal is to open .pdf file in a frame so that I can open together with another .htm page in one window:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim buffer As Byte()
    Using con As New SqlConnection()
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings()("SqlServerConnection").ConnectionString
        con.Open()
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT imageLaw FROM Laws WHERE ID = @ID", con)
            Dim pID As New SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
            pID.Value = CType(Request.QueryString("pID"), Integer)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(pID)
            buffer = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
    sFilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()
    System.IO.File.Move(sFilePath, System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf"))
    sFilePath = System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(sFilePath, ".pdf")
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(sFilePath, buffer)
    'Literal1.Text = "<frame  src=\"" + sFilePath + " \ ">"

    'TextBox1.Text = sFilePath
    ' ''Response.WriteFile(sFilePath)
    ' ''Response.End()
    ' ''Response.BinaryWrite(buffer)
    'Dim act As Action(Of String) = New Action(Of String)(AddressOf OpenFilePW)
    'act.BeginInvoke(sFilePath, Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub

Private Shared Sub OpenFilePW(ByVal sFilePath As String)

    Using p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
        p.StartInfo = New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(sFilePath)
        p.Start()
        p.WaitForExit()
        Try
            System.IO.File.Delete(sFilePath)
        Catch
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
```

I'm remarking last rows because I don't want .pdf file to be opened outside the web page.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a asp:Literal as container for your frame's HTML, or use the <%= Variable %> tag...
Solution 1 :

```
<frameset cols="100%,*">
<asp:Literal ID="litFrame" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</frameset>

and in CB : litFrame.Text = "<frame name=\"main\" target=\"main\" src=\"" + FilePathName + "\">";
```

Solution 2 :
In ASPX :

```
<frameset cols="100%,*">
<frame name="main" target="main" src="<%= myTarget %>">";
</frameset>
```

PS : frames are deprecated in web since more than 10 years...

Comment: gave me this err: Conversion from string "<frame  src=\" + FilePathName + " to type 'Long' is not valid

Comment: also 2nd solution not recognized myTarget , how Ive to declare it in code-behind.

Comment: Long ? Text property of Literal control expect a string, juste like the variable you build on the right. Could you post more code ?

Comment: in this example, mytarget should not be a local variable. Personnaly i prefer the first solution, i was just trying to point out that there is many ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: BTW, my example for code behind assignment was written in C#, you need to do some (very very small and easy) adjustments to make it work with VB, like correct string escaping, use & concatenation operator, remove the ; at the end... Maybe that's the problem, especially the + operator ? Sorry if I missed that your question was for VB.